# Language in PSPACE that isn't PSPACE-hard and isn't in PH

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Can there exist a language L in PSPACE such that L isn't PSPACE-hard and L isn't in the polynomial hierarchy (PH)? Intuitively, it seems like the answer is no, since TQBF is PSPACE-complete, and any version of TQBF bounded finitely to i alternating quantifiers is complete for one part (depending on whether it starts with the existential or universal quantifier) of the i-th level of the polynomial hierarchy. But, I'm unsure how one might go past this intuition to make a convincing argument.

To put it more abstractly, I'm wondering if there can exist a set of languages "layered" between PH and PSPACE, or whether the completeness of these QBF problems constrains their boundary (if there is one -- open question, I know) to have no such fillable gap.

Comment: You might want to look into generalized versions of Ladner's theorem and specifically the references and results given [in this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/799/generalized-ladners-theorem).

Comment: Watercrystal’s comment is spot on, but let me add that the [counting hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:C#ch) (and all its individual levels from the 2nd upwards) is included between PH and PSPACE, presumably strictly.